# returning a string (char *) from a c function from a static library (.lib)

Tags: c

I have a C static library and within it I have one function named returnBytes(), this function is defined this way:

```
extern "C" unsigned char * returnBytes(void)
{
      static unsigned char result[50] = { 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0 };
      return result;
}
```

on my other project which is using the above static library (.lib) I call the function like this:

```
  unsigned char *output = returnBytes();
```

but when I print the content of output, its not correct. meaning that calling a custom print function like this does not return the correct values:

```
print_bytes(output, 50);
```

On the other hand calling returnBytes() from within the library works fine. Meaning that the values 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0 are printed.

Does the *static* keyword only maintains the variable values within the *same* project? Could it be that the static keyword doesn't work if used within a static library function that is called from a c lient project?

Should I be using malloc instead and pass a pointer to returnBytes()? is that the only way?

I am running Windows 7, and I using VC12 for compiler for library and client of library.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst, that is not correct. He has a `static` variable.

Comment: Whoops, I overlooked that.

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is awfully darn vague.  You want to tell us what the *actual* result is, and how it differs from the *expected* result? and how you demonstrated that? (did you use `printf`? or something more sophisticated?)

Comment: @abelenky I printf the bytes on the caller function. When the caller is another function within the library the output is printed properly, but when the caller is a separate program, then the output is not correct, meaning random values are printed.

Comment: Given this incomplete information, I can't see any reason why it shouldn't work. So, please give a complete code example and the output you get. And what does random mean? Different on each run?

Comment: “Does the static keyword only maintain […]?”—no. And for everything else, we need a _complete_, _compilable_ example _and_ the output you've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry didn't notice the static. With the static it works.
I just tested your code on osx and it works correctly as below.

test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
   unsigned char * returnBytes(void); 
#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif  /* TEST_H */
```

test.c :

```
unsigned char * returnBytes(void)
{
      static unsigned char result[50] = { 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0 };
      return result;
}
```

Built as a library libtest.a and called by main.c in other project

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

#include "./test.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    unsigned char *c = returnBytes();
    printf("%x %x %x\n", c[0], c[1], c[2]);

    c[1]= 0xd0;

    c = returnBytes();
    printf("%x %x %x\n", c[0], c[1], c[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
f0 f0 f0
f0 d0 f0
```

which means you can both read and write.

Answer (score 0):

`static` only works inside your function. Moreover any usual variable (located in the stack) will always die at the end of the function, hence the wrong result.

To fix this, use a dynamic allocation ***inside your function***:

```
  unsigned char *result = calloc(50, 1);
  result[0] = 0x50;
  result[1] = 0x50;
  result[2] = 0x50;
  return result;
```

Comment: The variable is declared `static`. It doesn't die when the function returns.

Comment: I never said so. This was for the other ones. For the static I said that it only works (stays alive) inside your function. But maybe I formulated this wrongly.

Comment: A function can return the address of a `static` variable. The address will be valid in the calling function. What do you mean by 'stays alive inside your function'?

Comment: @ValentinMercier See [C11 6.2.4p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p3).  I'd expect `result` to be available for the duration of the program.

Comment: Well, I did not know that. Then I guess my answer may not solve the problem, if a `static` variable can be accessed by the calling function.

Comment: Thank you @ValentinMercier this does fix the issue but I have to free the memory everytime. I wish the `static` declaration would work somehow.

Comment: How often do you allocate memory using this function? You would also allocate memory if you used the static approach. Unless you reuse the same variable, but you can also do that with my solution. Explain me your issue and I will help you.